Preventing Unnecessary Rebuilds in BlocBuilder with Form State Management
I have a state (formState) and multiple form-based input widgets like TextFormField, Dropdown, and others. Each widget has an onChange function and events, and the widgets are wrapped around a BlocBuilder. In the state, I have a Map called formData, where I store the user input.
The issue is that when the state triggers and changes formData, it causes every BlocBuilder subscribed to that state to rebuild. I have used buildWhen to prevent unnecessary rebuilds, but it is not working as expected.
I will add some code snippets to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.
UI to Build Fields
class BuildFormFields {
  static Widget buildFormField(FormItem field, BuildContext context) {
    var temp = '''{
      "data_1": "option 1",
      "data_2": "option 2",
      "data_3": "option 3"
}''';

    Map<String, dynamic> payload = jsonDecode(temp);
    Map<String, Future<Map<String, dynamic>>> dropdownOptions = {};
    dropdownOptions['dropdownOptions'] = Future.value(payload);

    final formBloc = context.read<FormBloc>();
    switch (field.type) {
      case "textfield":
        formBloc
            .add(FormEventSetTextFormController(controller: field.variable!));
        return BlocBuilder<FormBloc, FormStat>(buildWhen: (previous, current) {
          log("pre ${previous.formData[field.variable]} ,${field.variable}");
          log("curr ${current.formData[field.variable]},${field.variable}");
          return previous.controllers[field.variable]?.text ==
              current.controllers[field.variable]?.text;
        }, builder: (context, state) {
          log("REBUILD Happened textfield ${field.variable}, ${state.formData}");
          return CustomTextFormField(
            initialValue: state.controllers[field.variable]?.text,
            isRequired: field.isRequired ?? true,
            fieldName: field.enLabel!,
            controller: state.controllers[field.variable],
            onSaved: (value) {
              formBloc.add(FormEventOnSavedClickOrOnChanged(
                  variable: field.variable!.trim(), value: value));
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              formBloc.add(FormEventOnSavedClickOrOnChanged(
                  variable: field.variable!.trim(), value: value));
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          );
        });
      case "dropdown":
        log("dropdown");
        // return Container();
        return BlocBuilder<FormBloc, FormStat>(builder: (context, state) {
          return
              // Text("dropdown");
              CustomDropdown(
            formData: state.formData,
            field: field,
            parentNotifier: (variable) {
              // _parentNotifier(variable);
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              log("dropdown_onchanged_value ${value}");
              formBloc.add(FormEventOnSavedClickOrOnChanged(
                  variable: field.variable!.trim(), value: value));
            },
            dropdownOptions: dropdownOptions,
          );
        });
      case "textview":
        formBloc
            .add(FormEventSetTextFormController(controller: field.variable!));
        // add dependencies and and contoller
        formBloc.add(FormEventRegisterDependencies(
            dependencies: field.dependencies!, variableName: field.variable));
        return BlocBuilder<FormBloc, FormStat>(builder: (context, state) {
          bool dependenciesMet = true;
          if (dependenciesMet) {
            formBloc.add(FormEventApiCalls(endpoint: field.endpoint));
            return CustomTextFormField(
              isRequired: field.isRequired ?? true,
              fieldName: field.enLabel!,
              readOnly: true,
              controller: state.controllers[field.variable],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            );
          }
          //  else {
          //   return Container();
          // }
        });
      case "single_checkbox_bool":
        return BlocBuilder<FormBloc, FormStat>(builder: (context, state) {
          return Text("single_checkbox_bool");
        });
      default:
        return Text("Unknown widget Type");
    }
  }
@freezed
class FormStat with _$FormStat {
  const factory FormStat(
      {AppForm? baseFormUiModel,
      dynamic stepFormUiModel,
      @Default({}) Map<String, dynamic> formData,
      @Default({}) Map<String, TextEditingController> controllers,
      @Default({}) Map<String, Set<String>> registrar}) = _FormStat;
}
FutureOr<void> onFormEventOnSavedClickOrOnChanged(
    FormEventOnSavedClickOrOnChanged event,
    Emitter<FormStat> emit,
  ) async {
    // Copy the existing form data map to modify it
    final updatedFormData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(state.formData);
    final updatedContoller =
        Map<String, TextEditingController>.from(state.controllers);

    // Update the corresponding field value
    updatedFormData[event.variable] = event.value;
    updatedContoller[event.variable]?.text = event.value!;

    // Emit the new state with the updated formData
    emit(state.copyWith(
        controllers: updatedContoller, formData: updatedFormData));

    log("Updated Form Data: ${state.formData}");
  }

